# Read more button smarty

Tags: php, smarty

**What i want:**
I'm new to smarty and I want to expand text that i retrieve from my database with a read more button..

**What i have:**
I already display the description shortened by using |substr but i dont know how to expand the text by using a button

**My code:**

```
{foreach $topics.topics as $topicss}
<p>
{$topicss.omschrijving|substr:0:50}
</p>

<button id="btn">Read more...</button>
{/foreach}
```

Ty:)

Comment: There is no smarty-native solution to but writing your own code/module to solve it

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your solution will probably be as JS module, since smarty doest not have (as far as i know) a native solution built in

Comment: After a quick google, this might be a good place to start.
https://justmarkup.com/log/2017/01/truncating-and-revealing-text-the-show-more-and-read-more-patterns/

Comment: ID must be unique the above code will generate multiple buttons with same id